# HTML form cursor position is in the middle

Tags: html, css

For some reason when my form displays, the text content is aligned half way up vertically. I'm not sure why? I'm using Sinatra on Ruby.

HTML:

```
<form action="/create" method="post">
  <h1>Arrays:</h2><br>
  <input type="text" name="file" value="<%= @contents1 %>" id="form">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfgP9/)

Comment: could you post some dummy content of your form or a screenshot of whats happening?

Comment: Jack's sorted my problem. I needed <textarea> not <input text='text'>. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `<input type='text'>` is only designed to deal with a single line of text.  Did you mean to use `<textarea>` instead?